# Find the maximum and minimum $(x,y)$ values for the equation:

Tags: trigonometry

> $$f(x)=3\sin\left(x-\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)$$

Amplitude= $3$

Period= $2 \pi$

Midline= $y=0$

Phase Shift= $\frac{5 \pi}{6}$

I found the maximum to be $(\frac{9 \pi}{8}, 3)$, and the minimum to be $(\frac{17 \pi}{8}, -3)$. Neither were correct, and I don't know what else to do. I must have answered them each 7 times. Help please! Thank you!

Comment: Oh yes, I see. I really do apologize! It is a sine equation.  So the full equation is f(x)= 3sin(x- 5pi/6)

Comment: What do you mean by maximum and minimum $(x,y)$ ? As you've written, the amplitude is 3, so the maximum and minimum y value you can attain is $3$ and $-3$, however this function is periodic for all possible x, so there are an infinite amount of x values which will provide you with 3 or -3

Comment: $$\frac {9\pi}8 - \frac{5\pi}6 = \frac{7\pi}{24}$$ $\sin \frac{7\pi}{24} \ne 1$, so no, you have not found the correct maximum (and similarly for the minimum). Brush up on your fractions. Whether they are willing to settle for a maximum and minimum, or want formulas that provide them all as Hushus46 indicates is another matter. If they are demanding all maximums and minimums, recall that $\sin(\theta + 2k\pi) = \sin(\theta)$ for all integers $k$.

Comment: They would like x and y coordinates for the maximum and minimum closest to (0,0) on the graph, so x-values for the coordinates should reside between 0 and 2 pi on a graph.  Obviously noted by the amplitude, the y-value will be 3 for the max or -3 for the min.